# How to remove repititve pattern from an image

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, ocr

I have to clean images for my OCR. Some of them have text of quite pale gray color above complex background.
[image: original] 
After some modifications I've got result like this:
[image: modified]
Can I remove this repititve squama-like pattern without bluring and denoising because it prevents the first symbol 'x' and last '6' from recognition?

I'm currently working with cropped fields and don't have big picture with me). Here is link for  [original images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18RHAAfccuq4vJwqJTXdKzQmtaqoKh2bU?usp=sharing)

FFT did some job with that weird mask, but it isn't ok. [image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please show the whole picture, unfiltered.

Comment: @SuddenWind "*remove repetitive pattern*", the first solution that comes to mind is [FFT Filtering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mLeVn8xzMw), see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483030/notch-reject-filtering-in-python/65484007) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480162/how-to-remove-repititve-pattern-from-an-image-using-fft)

Comment: @Bilal Thank you for your links. This course is great, i'll try to learn it.

Comment: @SuddenWind please explain what have you done and how you did it **in terms of code in your question**, to provide a  [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Bilal Can't we just imagine that original image is black and white one? The goal is to clean background. Is it possible with that image?