# How to remove white lines from an image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, fft

i want to remove the white lines in my img. but when i do it its very gray and not clean. can someone help me with it?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make your question explicit. How is the code related to the question? How is the image of Lena related to your "image of skin colour"? Is the actual distortion in the image caused by the scanner's individual sensors not being calibrated?

Comment: @Bilal wow, that first sentence is identical in both questions. Is this an exercise for an image processing course somewhere?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605438/i-have-a-class-work-to-filter-out-the-signal-which-creates-the-bars-of-the-fence

Comment: this is my question too.. its close there so i opened new one

Comment: @CrisLuengo This was the [original excercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483030), the other question is more like a use case ;)